# mongodb connection takes ~10 seconds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timeout

My Node.js application has a MongoDB connection, which when running on localhost connects immediately.
When I'm running it on a shared hosting server, it takes at least 10 sec to connect every time.
What I have tried so far, but did not help:
changing connection parameters as follows:

```
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    connectTimeoutMS:3600000,
    keepAlive:3600000,
    socketTimeoutMS:3600000
```

Also tried using [MongoHeartbeat](https://github.com/auth0/mongo-heartbeat) to keep the connection alive, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

keepalive probably needs to be lower, not higher. but 10 seconds sounds a lot like a timeout, can you get better logs? is there a proxy like nginx in between that cuts the connection? do you control all involed machines?

Comment: Changing keepalive to a small number unfortunately didnt help either.
I am using CPanel, and the Setup Node.js utility, so I don't think I have control over the connection. The only thing I'm getting in the error log is as follows:
[ N 2020-10-22 15:06:49.8099 571492/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1117 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 594802, (...)